# Tensorflow unable to load model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I trained some models in a docker. I am trying to load the models on my host machine but I am unable to do so.

At first I saved the models as .keras files as mentionned on the documentation. When trying to load the model using `tf.keras.models.load_model("model.keras")`, I get the following error:

- OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)

I trained the models again and saved them as .h5 files this time, which led to two different errors depending on the model I was trying to load:

- TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fn'
- ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to a Dense layer should be defined. Found None. Full input shape received: (None, None)

I could not find any information on how to fix these errors, I would love some help!

Comment: This sounds like you are not using the same version of Keras for saving and loading the model.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy thanks I'm training the model with the same tensorflow version (2.11.0). I'll see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Dr.Snoopy in the comments, loading the models with the same tensorflow version (here 2.11.0) solves the problem.